# rank() in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

A quick question - I wrote this piece of code:

```
SELECT memid, facid, starttime, slots,
SUM(slots) over(partition by memid ORDER BY starttime), 
rank() over(partition by memid)
FROM cd.bookings;
```

I would expect it to output for me something like that:

```
memid  facid  starttime  slots  sum  rank
  0      2    2012-07-01   2     2     1
  0      5    2012-07-02   2     4     1
  0      1    2012-07-03   2     6     1
  0      2    2012-07-04   2     8     1
  0      3    2012-07-05   2     10    1
  1      2    2012-07-01   2     2     2
  1      2    2012-07-02   2     4     2
  1      2    2012-07-03   2     6     2
  1      2    2012-07-04   2     8     2
  .      .         .       .     .     .
  .      .         .       .     .     .
  .      .         .       .     .     .
  n     ...       ...     ...   ...    X
```

So, I was expecting it to asign an incremented rank value for each memid. **However, instead the rank column is always stuck at 1.** I have tried to switch it up with dense_rank() function as well, but it also doesn`t work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use the ORDER BY in your RANK() like you do it in your SUM(). The RANK() needs an ORDER BY...The SUM() not so much :)

Comment: problem lies in partition by memid i think, try this: dense_rank() over(order by memid)

Comment: Thank you guys, both solutions worked for me! :)